# LSTM Layer accuracy is 0

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm

i have  network that gets 9 days and predict 10s day price using lstm
my x shape is (240,9,1) and y shape is (240,1,1)
the problem is accuracy is 0
can anyone help

here is my code

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units=50, input_shape=(train_x.shape[0], 1), return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(units=25))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(units=1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(), metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())
model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=100, batch_size=64)
```

and also extra questions
what is batch_size and units of lstm and droupout

thanks for help

Comment: I could be wrong in the context of Tensorflow, but I would expect accuracy is more relevant for classification rather than regression. Your problem is regression -- you're not just outputting a 0 or 1, but rather a real-valued price. So accuracy is (I would guess) computing how many predicted prices are exactly the same as the actual price, which would be 0. You may want to use a different metric than accuracy.

Comment: I don't get it.

Comment: Imagine the 9 days' prices are `[1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5, 6.6, 7.7, 8.8, 9.9]` and the true 10th day's price is `11`. Let's say your model predicts `10.9`. That's close to the true price of `11`, indicating that your model is good. But accuracy only cares if `10.9 == 11`. It's not, so that prediction is "wrong". Even if your model predicted `10.999999`, that still wouldn't exactly equal the target price. So, none of your predictions exactly match the targets, and your accuracy is 0%. A better metric might be something like mean squared error. Does that make more sense?

Comment: oh you mean the accuracy is not the point I'm looking for, but I need accuracy for my report.
if I send my code and data to you can you help?